# Não é possível editar o 'Resumo da edição'?

Tags: suporte

No momento em que eu estava incluindo o 'resumo da edição' [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81834/biblioteca-que-leia-texto-e-transforme-em-%c3%a1udio) acidentalmente bati o dedo no <kbd>enter</kbd>, eis o resultado:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Eu iria escrever "*Removendo algumas tags visto que o AP pediu uma solução com Nodejs*", mas aconteceu isso. Até tentei editar rapidamente:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Mas o resumo acaba voltando pro antigo (no caso, o errado). O estranho é que qualquer edição feita na pergunta permanece, já uma alteração em um 'Resumo de edição' feito por mim não fica gravado.

Minha pergunta é: Não é possível editar o 'Resumo da edição' ou isso é um bug?

Comment: Acho que se você precisa fazer também uma alteração na publicação. Para esse caso você poderia apenas adicionar uma linha ao final dela que já aceitaria a edição do seu resumo.

Comment: Vou tentar na próxima @Math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se fizer dentro do perído de graça de 5 minutos (grace period, não sei a tradução oficial pra PT), é só incluir um caractere qualquer no corpo do texto (pode ser um espaço em branco) que poderá alterar o resumo.

Também pode incluir um caractere normal, tipo um ponto `.`, alterar o resumo, voltar a editar, remover o ponto e salvar.

Acho que o sistema não considera alterar o resumo como uma "edição". Tem que editar o *post* mesmo e aí dá pra fazer a alteração do resumo.